# Azure Sql Table Partition Performance

Tags: sql-server, azure, partitioning, query-performance

I am using Azure SQL. **I found the select performance of table partition is slower than the original**. Can Sql Server table partition actually improve the select performance? As the Partition count increases the query performance degrades (i.e. 36 partition, 915 partition).

Also, what's the method to avoid partition scan and do normal table heap scan in a partitioned table?

Comment: Have you read the [partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/data-partitioning) documentation? Try to add more relevant information to your question based on this article.

Comment: Why did you expect partitioning would improve `SELECT` performance? In most cases it won't compared with just having an index with leading column of whatever your partition key is. The advantages of partitioning are mostly for writes (with being able to swap in and out partitions or perform maintenance on individual partitions)

Answer (score 0):

1.About Partitioned Tables.

If your table has large data, you can use the table and index partitioning.
One of the benefits of partitioning is that:

You may improve query performance, based on the types of queries you frequently run and on your hardware configuration. For example, the query optimizer can process equi-join queries between two or more partitioned tables faster when the partitioning columns in the tables are the same, because the partitions themselves can be joined.

Here is the documentation:[Partitioned Tables and Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

When you run the `select` query of a partition table, the query will search from your partitions until the data you need is found. So the select performance may be slower than original sometimes.

2.When your table is creating, you must need to specify if it is the partition table. Once the table is created as the partition table, you could not change it. I didn't find the method for you, I guess maybe that's not supported.

I hope it can helps you.